# Abstract base class member function called from derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

I am still trying to grip the concept of Abstract Base Classes and what can and cannot be done from the Derived class.

I have the following code :

```
class NpBaseTest {
    ...
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const NpBaseTest& p_npBaseTest);
    /* Implemented in the .cpp file as -
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const NpBaseTest& p_npBaseTest)
    {
        p_npBaseTest.show(os);
        return os;
    }
    */
    virtual uint16_t process(int) const = 0;

    virtual void show(std::ostream& os) const
    {
        os
            << "Test ID [" << get_test_id() << "] "
            << "Module Type [" << get_module_type() << "]" << std::endl;
    }
};

class CavTest : public NpBaseTest
{
    ...
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const CavTest& p_cavtest);
    /* Implemented in the .cpp file as
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const CavTest& p_cavtest) 
    {
        p_cavtest.show(os);
        return os;
    }
    */

    uint16_t process(int p_val) const
    {
        //...implemented here
    }

    void show(std::ostream& os) const
    {
        NpBaseTest::show(os);
        os
            << "CavTest Type" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

What I am hoping to do in the derived class show function, call the show function from the base class but I get the following error.
What I understand is since NpBaseTest is an ABC it doesn't instantiate an object when the Derived class object is instantiated. 
So what are my options for achieving the desired functionality ?

Error message :

> components/cavium/CavTest.cpp: In function 'void show(std::ostream&)':
>   components/cavium/CavTest.cpp:20: error: cannot call member function
>   'virtual void NpBaseTest::show(std::ostream&) const' without object

UPDATE : 
Initial issue solved.
Looking for more advice
Is there a better way to call the base class function without having to specify the base class name with this->::show(os) ?

SOLUTION : 
I changed the base class `show()` routine to be a non virtual private member function which in turn calls a pure virtual `show_all(ostream &os)` function implemented by each derived class. That way I do no have to redefine the `operator<<` for every derived class and can avoid using `<BaseClassName>::show()`

Example in Base Class -

```
void NpBaseTest::show(std::ostream& os) const
{
    //Do base functionality here
    os
        << "Test ID [" << get_test_id() << "] "
        << "Module Type [" << get_module_type() << "]" << std::endl;

    // Call derived class routine here
    show_all(os); //This is declared as virtual void show_all(ostream& os) const = 0;
}
```

In Derived class

```
void CavTest::show_all(std::ostream& os) const
{
    os
        << "CavTest Type" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Which error exactly?

Comment: Please reduce your program to the smallest possible **complete** program that demonstrates the error. Please [edit] your question and copy-paste that entire short program into your question. Please copy-paste any error messages into your question. See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: NpBaseTest::show has been defined incorrectly, you should lose the NpBaseTest:: at the start of show

Comment: Try `this->NpBaseTest::show(os);`. But it should actually compile from what you're showing.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ : Yup that worked. I had initially tried that but had some missing parts in the class. Thanks !

Comment: @MooingDuck as I said, in the declaration, the class::function is not required as the implementation is already in the class declaration - *I'm not referring to the function call*

Comment: @ImNot Just out of curiosity: Which compiler are you using? As mentioned `this->` should be implicit for an inherited virtual function override.

Comment: @UKMonkey `NpBaseTest::` is there to call the base class impl. instead of the derived class impl. of `show`

Comment: @alain will you please re-read my comment *NOT REFERRING TO THE FUNCTION CALL*

Comment: @UKMonkey yes. You're right. Sorry.

Comment: The issue is the formatting of the question hides that it's inside the class declaration.

Comment: So - like I said before; I'd bin the class:: inside it's declaration, since this can cause problems on some compilers as it mangles the name more

Comment: Yes. This has caused confusion many times (with me, at least). I'm used to trust the indentation, but here on SO I should definitely not rely on that. Sigh.

Comment: Is there a better way to call the base class function without having to specify the base class name with `this-><BaseClassName>::show(os)` ?

Comment: @ImNot no, because the class could have multiple base classes with a `show(...)` method, so you have to tell it which base class to use.

Answer (score 0):

As shown your current problems have nothing to do with abstract (a.k.a. pure virtual) methods because there are none of those involved.

#### Problem 1: member function declaration syntax

The base class `show()` has an extra `NpBaseTest::` qualifier that should not be there. You only need that extra qualifier when you define a member function outside the class declaration. The usual scenario for this:

```
// Foo.hpp
class Foo
{
    void bar();
}

// Foo.cpp
#include "Foo.hpp"
void Foo::bar()
{
    // ...
}
```

That’s the most likely reason for the error message you show.

#### Problem 2: visibility

The base class `show()` is private because in a `class` the default visibility is `private`. You cannot call private base class methods from a derived class, i.e. your call to `NpBaseTest::show()` – though syntactically correct – will not compile.

#### Problem 3: class declaration syntax

Both class declarations miss a ; after their closing brace.

The bare bones changes to get this to compile are:

```
class NpBaseTest
{
protected: // or: public:
    virtual void show(std::ostream& os) const { /*...*/ }
};

class CavTest : public NpBaseTest
{
    // private by default
    // Works because you can override with a lower visibility,
    // but not with a higher one.

    void show(std::ostream& os) const override
    {
        NpBaseTest::show(os);
        // ...
    }
};
```

`override` is optional but highly recommended if you use a C++11 capable (i.e. non-ancient) compiler.